# WordPress. Как правильно подключить файл из плагина?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

В WP есть функция get_template_part() которая подключает файлы из выбранной темы.

А как правильно подключить файл из плагина таким же способом?

При помощи plugin_dir_path() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно делают так. В главном файле плагина определяют константу

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
```

и дальше уже используют пути относительно неё:

```
require_once MY_PLUGIN_PATH . '/includes/class-main.php';
```